# Facebook Error Code=7 in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented the `Login With Facebook` in my app. I got the user_information from Account Settings.

**Problem:** Everything works fine, but **for only one account** I got the error message like

```
error: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill
this access request: Invalid application xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" UserInfo=0xbee2b90
{NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: 
Invalid application xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

**My code is as follow:**

```
-(IBAction)actFacebook:(id)sender{

  if(!_accountStore)
    _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];



 NSArray *fbAccounts =[[NSArray alloc]init];
fbAccounts= [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
```

NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_birthday", nil];

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         FAppId, ACFacebookAppIdKey,permissions , ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                         nil];

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount  options:options
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if(granted)
     {
         NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
         _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

         [_accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:_facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
             //we don't actually need to inspect renewResult or error.
             if (error){
                 NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);
             }
         }];
         NSLog(@"Success");
         [self FB_Detail];
     }
     else{
         // ouch
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

}

**I don't know why this happen only for one account?**

Comment: may be it comes  user privacy setting in their facebook account

Comment: @iDev, I think it comes due to Sandbox mode of the app. but how can I disable it?

Comment: you can disable it in Facebook application details console, by editing the app details in Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

New Facebook server only accept real app already on App Store by "iPhone Store ID" and "iPad Store ID". You can test this one with your old app (change bundle, Facebook ID).

You can use SLComposeViewController and change back to your way in next version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com and then Select your app.

Create test users from Roles.

Use that credentials of test users.